# How to avoid automated action beeing executed based on condition ? - Odoo

Tags: python, odoo, action, odoo-15

In Projects Module I created a automated action, which creates a new Project name, based on some fields from the sales order. When a project is automatically created from an confirmed sales order the automated action works fine.

Problem is that when I want to create an project manually, the automated action is also called, but there is no sales order behind the project, from which the name could be created.

How can I avoid the automated action beeing called, when I want to create an project manually ?

The code from my automated action:

```
name = record.sale_order_id.partner_id.name
shortage = ("".join(name.split()[0]))
sum_of_qty = 0

fc_numbers = []
for line_id in record.sale_line_id.order_id.order_line :
  if line_id.x_studio_product_type == "service" and line_id.x_studio_create_on_order == "task_in_project" :
    sum_of_qty += int(line_id.product_uom_qty)
    if not line_id.x_studio_fc:
      fc_numbers.append("TBD")
    elif line_id.x_studio_fc not in fc_numbers :
      fc_numbers.append(line_id.x_studio_fc)
record["name"] = (' / '.join(fc_numbers)  + " - " + record.sale_order_id.name + " - " + shortage + " - " + str(sum_of_qty) +" MT")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's better to include your action inside the sale-order model, instead of using automated actions. you could do it like this:

```
from odoo import api, models


class Order(models.Model):
    _inherit = "sale.order"

    def action_confirm(self):
        super().action_confirm()
        self._on_order_confirmed_automated_action()

    @api.onchange("state")
    def _on_order_confirmed_automation(self)
        for order in self:
            if order.state == "sale":
                # Your code here
```